# What is the equivalent of domain/range in 3 dimensions for the z variable?

Tags: vectors

I am well aware of how in the two dimensional plane, the domain is the set of all x values and the range is the set of all y values.
However, when working in three dimensions, what is the equivalent term for the restriction of the z values?
Obviously the domain and range are still the set of x and y values, but how could one describe the set of z values?

Comment: The domain of $f(x,y)$ is the set of all points $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f(x,y)$ is defined. The range is the set of values $f(x,y)$ that the function $f$ can realize, as $(x,y)$ varies in the domain. Note that the domain is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, while the range is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. If we regard the outputs of $f$ as $z$-values, then the range of $f$ is the set of all $z$-coordinates of points $(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3$ which satisfy the equation $z=f(x,y)$ (i.e., $z$-coordinates of points on the graph of $f$).

Comment: For *any* function, the domain is the set of inputs and the range is the set of outputs.